# My tkinter window with a scrollbar is lagging

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to preface this by saying I'm not as good at python as many of you are. I don't know how classes work for example. But I know all the basics and some specifics.

Anyway the issue I'm currently having is that I have a window with many checkboxes and a scrollbar, and when I scroll down it lags heavily. Here's some photos:

[Photo of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT4kW.png)

[Photo of the window when I scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEKcb.png)

The lag goes away, it just takes a few moments.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
vscrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
c = Canvas(root,yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)
vscrollbar.config(command=c.yview)
vscrollbar.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
f=Frame(c)
c.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
c.create_window(0,0,window=f, anchor='nw')
# creates the variables that store the values of the checkboxes
job_dictionary = {}
with open("jobs.txt","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        job_dictionary[line.replace("\n","")] = IntVar()
# row_ and column_ are used to determine the grid placement of all the checkbuttons.
row_ = 2
column_ = 0
for line in sorted(job_dictionary.keys()):
    Checkbutton(f, text=line.replace("\"",""), variable=job_dictionary[line]).grid(row=row_, column=column_, sticky=W)
    row_ += 1
    if row_ > 60:
        row_ = 2
        column_ += 1
root.update()
c.config(scrollregion=c.bbox("all"))

root.mainloop()
```

The values for each checkbox is stored as a value in a dictionary. `row_` and `column_` are used to determine the placement of each checkbox within the frame. The code to use a scrollbar and a frame at the same time was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237310/tkinter-canvas-scrollbar).

Comment: When I run your code using my own `jobs.txt` file with roughly 130 jobs in it, I don't see an excessive amount of lag. Please provide a [mre] (including the contents of the `jobs.txt` file).

Comment: @martineau [this is the link to the jobs.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EFeQE0WGJrLLJqM5X0UiaeONjyzb0l5k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Still can't reproduce the problem…your file is only about 4x larger than the one I was using. As I suggested previously, post a [mre].

Comment: @martineau I'm not sure how I would make the code more concise. I added the from tkinter import * and I changed line1 to line (I made a typo), so now the code works when directly copy pasted. Using this code reproduces the error for me.

Comment: That's about all I did to make something runnable (plus adding a `root.mainloop()` at the very end). Unfortunately, it's difficult to help when the problem can't be reproduced. Note my computer system is several years old, so I doubt it's a hardware speed issue.

Comment: @martineau thanks for trying. I guess I'll wait until somebody else can reproduce it. Maybe I'll send it to a friend to see if it's just an issue on my computer.

Comment: I can confirm lag when in fullscreen, but I don't see what could possibly be changed to fix it. Maybe use a Notebook or some kind of pagination and split the jobs up in groups of 50 or so.

Comment: @Michael Guidry thanks for the confirmation. I was hoping to avoid that but it looks like it might be the best way to do this. I'm thinking I'll have it create a new window to "flip the page". Do you know of any better ways to do that?